# Find min element in a nested List<List<String>> in groovy using collect?

Tags: groovy

I have written the below example of locating the `min` element in a nested `List<List<String>>` that works fine:

```
List<String> el0 = ["112", "2"]
List<String> el1 = ["11", "222", "45", "1"]
List<String> el2 = ["21", "112", "23"]

List<List<String>> container = new ArrayList<>()

container << el0
container << el1
container << el2

List<String> candidates = container.collect { it.min(new Comparator<String>() {
  @Override
  int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    return Integer.valueOf(o1) <=> Integer.valueOf(o2)

  }
}) }

String min = candidates.min()
println (min)
```

But are there optimizations/simplification that can be done to the above rather verbose example - assuming the elements needs to be strings (and in the future more complex objects)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simplified way can locate the min in one operation after flattening `container` (min reduction is done just once). It can look like:

```
String min = container.flatten().min{Integer.valueOf(it)}
```

As can be seen, I also used `{Integer.valueOf(it)}` as a closure to implement `Comparator<String>`, which you did using an anonymous class.

Comment: Another option is `List<String> candidates = container*.min {Integer.valueOf(it) }`

Comment: @tim_yates I'd expect that to produce a list with the min in each sublist... Unless another `min()` is invoked on the result: `container*.min{Integer.valueOf(it)}.min{Integer.valueOf(it) }`

Comment: Yeah, I meant with the original `String min = candidates.min()` as in the question 

Comment: What does the container* do? And whats the name of that "operator"? I have tried to google it but not found any matches

Comment: @u123 It's the spread operator (or spread-dot operator), `*.`. Documentation is [here](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator). It invokes the method after the dot on each element of the collection on which it's applied, producing a new collection with the result of each call; as in `[1,2,3,4]*.plus(2) == [3, 4, 5, 6]`